# JQuery on form submit for appended form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that is appended to div on my web page when a user clicks on a button. I have JQuery that fires when a user clicks the button, this send an AJAX call to a PHP page that returns a form back to my AJAX and then it is appended to the div. Now, I am using JQuery to process this new form's submission, but it does not seem to work for the appended forms. Is this because the form was not there at first page load? What can I do?

The JQuery works fine with the exact same forms that are there from the start.

My JQUERY:

```
$(".comment-form").submit(function() {

    // Jquery form stuff 

});
```

Comment: you need to use delegation with a static parent element, http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Patrick, can you put your previous comment in an answer, and maybe elaborate as to why? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For dynamically added elements use this:

```
$(document).on('submit','.comment-form',function(){});
```

Comment: most event listener methods in jQuery now call `.on()` anyway so it is beneficial for you to just use it from the beginning and also learn the ins and outs of it because some of the others may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: @Tims this isn't working. Am I supposed to do:

$(document).on('submit','.comment-form',function(){ 

// code here

});

Comment: yes.  For more help please update your question with the rest of your html and js.

Comment: IT WORKS! I just had my selector wrong!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to bind the submit action to elements that are added to the DOM through javascript.

So after the form is added through javascript bind the submit function again.

```js
$('.comment-form').submit(function(){});
```